# Return templated containers from SO library in C++

Tags: c++, stl, shared-libraries

I want to return templated containers (such as `Vector<T>` or `List<T>`) from exported functions in `.so` library. That library uses its own version of STL and I can't just use `std::vector`.

I can create a new class for type `Obj`:

```
class ObjVector {
public:
    <...>
    Obj& operator[](size_t pos);
    void push_back(const Obj& obj);
private:
    class Impl;
    Impl *d_ptr;
};
```

And then define class `ObjVector::Impl` as `class ObjContainer::Impl: public std::vector<Obj>` and methods in libary source.

But how I can use templates for it? Because I need vectors for different types of objects.

Comment: Bad idea to derive from stl containers. Is there any particular reason you don't want to make `ObjVector` a template itself? With a simple definition `template <typename T> class ObjVector { std::vector<T> data;}` ? If you really want to use templates without any specialization, I am unaware of any way your code can reside in the cpp files as the entire class definition needs to be available at compile time. Must reside in a header.

Comment: It is fundamentally impossible to export templates from a shared library, or any kind of binary file. Such a file contains machine code - but templates don't get compiled to machine code. Only when a template is actually instantiated, with a particular set of arguments, that instantiation compiles to machine code, and can be exported from a library. Templates themselves must be available to the user in source code form.

Comment: Igor Tandetnik's comment is the correct answer.